# Xcode comment shortcut on spanish keyboard?

Tags: xcode, comments, xcode8, keyboard-shortcuts

Using a Spanish keyboard: how can I comment out multiple lines of text?

The keyboard shorcut <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>/</kbd> works fine on the English keyboard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Search for `comment` in Xcode help menu (i.e., the top bar above all windows). There should be a shortcut besides the menu item.

Otherwise, go to **Xcode→Preferences→Key Bindings** and add the desired shortcut yourself.

Comment: Perfect, I did that and found cmd-shift-7